# How to disable LOCAL INFILE in MySql 5.5 Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, security, configuration, ubuntu-12.04

Cannot disable LOCAL INFILE ( for security reasons ) in mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.25a, for debian-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 6.2 on ubuntu 12.04;
Here is my /etc/mysql/my.cnf

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
loose-local-infile=0
local-infile=0

[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
local-infile=0
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
```

I do

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart

mysql -u root -p

mysql> SELECT load_file("/etc/passwd");
```

And it shows me my /etc/passwd content. So it didn't work.

Comment: before firing your select query, try the statement "show variables like "load_infile"" and check if your change has taken effect or not.

Comment: SHOW VARIABLES shows | local_infile  | OFF

Comment: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/etc/passwd' INTO TABLE table1
    -> ;
ERROR 1148 (42000): The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version ===> ALL WORKS, but SELECT load_file("/etc/passwd"); loads file !

Comment: This belongs on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MySQL Docs for load_file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_load-file) reference, it can be seen that load_file is MySQL function that returns content of the file as string. It does nothing more than that. It has nothing to do with local_infile.

For security purpose, from same docs:

> If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory
>   name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.

So if you set the system variable "secure_file_priv", then file has to be present in that particular directory. Moreover, user requires File level privileges to execute this statement. Simply do not give file level privileges to your users who are accessing database, if you want it to be secured.

Further [local-infile](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-options.html#option_mysqld_local-infile) is for [LOAD DATA](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statements, which loads data into table, thereby affecting tables. It has nothing to do with load_file() function.